# Building of app during app deployment fails in Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, build

I tried deploying an app in Heroku ([the same one I tried asking about here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161060/dialogflow-app-does-not-get-deployed-in-heroku)), but although it deployed, I keep on getting the wrong output. So I deleted the deployed app (I deployed it using Heroku's website) and tried to deploy it by using Heroku CLI on cmd instead. but then suddenly the app won't deploy. I tried to deploy it using the website again, but it still won't deploy and keep on showing this error message

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  4.1.1
   engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

   Resolving node version 4.1.1...
   Downloading and installing node 4.1.1...
   Using default npm version: 2.14.4
-----> Restoring cache
   Skipping cache restore (not-found)
-----> Building dependencies
   Installing node modules (package.json)
   npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
   npm ERR! Linux 4.14.12-041412-generic
   npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_fd784069b3690d9546dfaea15e0e3251/digracesion-make-sandwich-0fe3e02/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_fd784069b3690d9546dfaea15e0e3251/digracesion-make-sandwich-0fe3e02/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_fd784069b3690d9546dfaea15e0e3251/digracesion-make-sandwich-0fe3e02/.npmrc"
   npm ERR! node v4.1.1
   npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4

   npm ERR! Invalid name: "Make Sandwich App"
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
   npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/build_fd784069b3690d9546dfaea15e0e3251/digracesion-make-sandwich-0fe3e02/npm-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

Comment: can you share the `package.json` file.

Comment: it's found here https://github.com/digracesion/make-sandwich/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Capital letters and spaces are not allows in the `name` field of `package.json`. change it to something like this `make-sandwich-app` in `package.json` file and try to deploy

Comment: tried switching it to make-sandwich but i still get the same result

Comment: op, it just turns out that the change i made didn't get committed properly. this worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed the capital letters and spaces in the name field like @Syed said and changed it to something like make-sandwich.

when this didn't worked, i check the files in the repository and realized that not all files were committed properly by trying the command

```
git status
```

so i committed all of the changes using these:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit comment here"
```

and then pushed the changes with the use of

```
git push heroku master
```